# How to use jquery ajax to get one variable from a php file to another php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having trouble passing a variable in my a php file to another php file using jquery ajax. I don't know why it doesn't read it though because everytime I echo the variable it's undefined or just plain blank.

teams.php

```
<?php
    // Display members from database
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'chansandbox');

    if(isset($_POST['display'])){
        $team = "SELECT * FROM team";
        $resultTeam = mysqli_query($connect, $team);
?>
        <ul class="teams">
                <li><a id="teamheader">LIST OF TEAMS</a></li>
        </ul>
<?php
        while($arrayTeam = mysqli_fetch_array($resultTeam)){
            $team_id = $arrayTeam['team_id'];
?>
            <ul class="teams" name="teamId" value="<?php echo $team_id ?>">
                <li><a href="#"><?php echo $arrayTeam['team_name']; ?></a>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li class="memberdivholder">
                            <div class="gradeview">
                                <h1 id='options'><i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                                    Options:
                                    <button class="topbutton">Grade Team</button>
                                    <button class="topbutton">View Team</button>
                                    <button class="teamdelete">Delete Team</button>
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                                $member = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE team_team_id = '$team_id' ORDER BY position_pos_id=17 desc";
                                $resultMember = mysqli_query($connect, $member);
                                while($arrayMember = mysqli_fetch_array($resultMember)){
                            ?>
                                <div class="memberholder">
                                    <h1 class="clearfix">
                                        <?php
                                            if($arrayMember['position_pos_id']==17){
                                                echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        <?php echo $arrayMember['emp_fname'] . " " . $arrayMember['emp_lname']; ?>
                                            <button class="viewprofile">View Profile</button>
                                    </h1>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                                }
                            ?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <?php
        }
        exit();
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
        ?>
```

script.js

```
$('.teams').on('click', '.teamdelete', function(){
    var teamId = $(.teams).attr("value");
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:81/chansandbox/wp-content/themes/Skeleton/teamdelete.php",
            method: "POST",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                team_id: teamId
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                eval(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

teamdelete.php

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'chansandbox');

    $team_id = $_POST['teamId'];

    $update = "UPDATE employee SET team_team_id = NULL WHERE team_team_id = '$team_id'";

    if(mysqli_query($connect, $update)){
        echo "Employees Updated";

        $deleteteam = "DELETE FROM team WHERE team_id = '$team_id'";

        if(mysqli_query($connect, $deleteteam)){
            echo "Team deleted '$team_id'";
        }
        else{
            echo "Team not deleted";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Employees not updated";
    }

    mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

As you can see I'm trying to get the value of the ul (class=teams) in the teams.php and passing it on to the js script file using ajax and `var teamId = $(this).attr("value");` and passing it onto teamdelete.php but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would really be appreciated thank you.

Comment: $team_id = $_POST['team_id']; try this

Comment: in your AJAX add `"dataType": "JSON",`

Comment: classes dont have values (well not in valid html)

Comment: In your `click`-event, `$(this)` is actually referring to `$('.teamdelete')` (which is the button and not the ul that has the value attribute).

Comment: @Shanukk It still doesn't work the error says Undefined index: team_id

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @Demonyowh it still doesn't work same error as the one Shanukk gave me

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've tried the name of the element and the class and it still doesn't work. It still says undefined index

Comment: I don't what you mean by that. You are currently fetching `value` from the clicked button, which doesn't have a value + that you're sendiing `team_id` and trying to fetch `teamId` (as @Shanukk pointed out). There isn't _one_ issue here, there are multiple.

Comment: In what file do you get the undefined index? In teams or teamdelete?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I mean I've already changed the selector to var teamId = $(.teams).attr("value"); so shouldn't it fetch the value of the element that I selected? Do same variable names matter on different files? If thats the case is team_id in the script the same as team_id in the php file? The errors are inside the teamdelete.php file

Comment: You define the names of the fields you are going to send: `team_id: teamId` = `team_id` will be posted. `hello: teamId` would post `$_POST['hello']`. Those _must_ be the same in both files.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes I see that now, thanks for you help, its working fine now thank you for you help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because $('.teamdelete') has no attr value ..
in your html you should put

```
<button class="teamdelete" value="<?php echo $arrayTeam['team_id']; ?>">Delete Team</button>
```

and in your javascript do this

```
var teamId = $(this).attr("value");
```

and in your php .. since the name of the post data = team_id you should do

```
$team_id = $_POST['team_id'];
```

Comment: I've changed the selector to the ul's name and even class and it still doesn't work. Though I haven't actually tried putting a value for the button so I'll try this and see if it'll work

Comment: it is because the class team delete that refers to the button does not have team_id value ..

Comment: @PaulJVC You're creating multiple `.team`-elements (it's in a while-loop), jquery doesn't know which you are referring to if you just do `$('.team').attr(...)`. You should do some `console.log()`'s in your scripts to see what the variables actually contains before posting them.

Comment: @Demonyowh I've changed it and it actually works now. Thank you for help me I really appreciate it. I though that just by changing the selector to the name or class of the ul it would go to that element and fetch the value, I guess not. Again thank you for you help!

Comment: @PaulJVC I am happy it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Your data variable is incorrect...

The ajax data is sent as `data: { NAME : VALUE }`. The PHP is essentially calling `$_POST['VALUE']` So the php doesn't know *what* that value is.

The PHP calls:

```
$_POST['teamId'];
```

But the ajax sends

```
team_id:
```

Try changing the PHP on teamdelete.php to:

```
$team_id = $_POST['team_id'];
```

There are additional issues as well...

html:

```
<button class="teamdelete" value="<?php echo $arrayTeam['team_id']; ?>" >Delete Team</button>
```

js:

```
$('.teams').on('click', '.teamdelete', function(){
    var teamId = $(this).attr("value"); // ------------ CHANGED 
    console.log(teamId); // ----------- CHANGED should show the right ID in console
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
        $.ajax({
            url: ".....teamdelete.php",
            method: "POST",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                team_id: teamId
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                eval(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'chansandbox');

    $team_id = $_POST['team_id']; // ----------- CHANGED

    $update = "UPDATE employee SET team_team_id = NULL WHERE team_team_id = '$team_id'";

    if(mysqli_query($connect, $update)){
        echo "Employees Updated";

        $deleteteam = "DELETE FROM team WHERE team_id = '$team_id'";

        if(mysqli_query($connect, $deleteteam)){
            echo "Team deleted '$team_id'";
        }
        else{
            echo "Team not deleted";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Employees not updated";
    }

    mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

You can use the developers panel and inspector to confirm that the delete button has the correct value for the team.

Comment: Yes I've already changed it and it's working fine now. Thank you for your help :) I though that just by changing the selector for the variable it would go to that element and fetch the value, I guess it doesn't though. Still I really appreciate your help, thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help.. good thing my answer helped Demonyowh include additional issues. :)